# Reduce multiple CSS transformations into fewer ones while maintaining position

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transforms

I have an element with a ton of CSS transformations like this:

```
transform:  translateX( 0 )
            translateY( -1rem )
            rotate( 45deg ) 
            translateY( -2.5rem )
            rotate( 45deg )
            translateY( 5rem );
```

The order of these properties matter as they affect how the element ends up being positioned on the page. I've done some tinkering and came up with the same exact end result with fewer properties:

```
transform:  rotate( 90deg ) translateX( -2.8rem ) translateY( 3.25rem );
```

You can test this by commenting and uncommenting out the comment in the snippet below to see nothing changes ( the transformations equal the same result ).

I did this manually and it took some time to find the exact transformations that would get me the same result. I'm trying to do this for literally thousands of properties in real time...

Is there a formula? Is there a CSS hack? Is there a simple way of doing this - I don't know where to start. O.o

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  padding: 2.5rem 1rem;
  background-color: #4cc;
  color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  
  transform:  translateX( 0 )
              translateY( -1rem )
              rotate( 45deg ) 
              translateY( -2.5rem )
              rotate( 45deg )
              translateY( 5rem );
  
/*transform:  rotate( 90deg ) translateX( -2.8rem ) translateY( 3.25rem );*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  transformed<br>element
</div>
```

**Edit: You might be wondering: Why do this!? Well here is a problem I had earlier: [Move transform-origin back to the center of the element in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724514/move-transform-origin-back-to-the-center-of-the-element-in-css). I solved it like this: [Transforms are added...endlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723656/transforms-are-added-endlessly?noredirect=1&lq=1) . But now I have endless transforms and this is why I ask.**

I have tons of dynamic transforms that look like this:
[image]

Comment: where you want to positioning it?

Comment: @dippas I just want it to re-write the transforms with fewer properties. The position can be anywhere. I need to make fewer properties but keep it in the same place and rotation.

Comment: If you want even less code, just use `transform: rotate( 90deg ) translate( -2.8rem, 3.25rem );`

Comment: Thanks @AnuragDaolagajao. Any idea how to do this systematically?

Comment: If you are dynamically adding those styles then just get "current-style" and add and overwrite it, instead of appending the transform with more values

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao That seems like a good suggestion on on the surface but If I don't append the transforms this happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724514/move-transform-origin-back-to-the-center-of-the-element-in-css. View animation in my snippet.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot transforms restart from their initial position. Maybe you could use `@keyframes`  instead of appending transforms

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll post the answer if I ever find it...lol

Comment: If you use `getComputedStyle` it will return a `matrix`, which will be shortest possible code...like this https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/7g7gk99s/ ... and with that you can either iterate through all elements or all classes and _shrink_ your code

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any other way, but came up with this "hacky" method based on keyframes

UPDATE: Removed jQuery

```js
var currentAngle = 0,
  styleElment = document.createElement('style'), // create a style element to insert dynamic keyframes
  styleSheet,
  animState = 0; // toggle between 2 animation states

document.head.appendChild(styleElment);
styleSheet = styleElment.sheet;

// insert 2 default keyframes to the created stylesheet
styleSheet.insertRule("@keyframes rotate_1 {0% {transform: rotate(0deg);} 100% {transform: rotate(0deg)}}"); // at index 1
styleSheet.insertRule("@keyframes rotate_2 {0% {transform: rotate(0deg);} 100% {transform: rotate(0deg)}}"); // at index 0

document.getElementById("rotateBtn").onclick = function() {
  var newAngle = currentAngle + 30,
    transformCSS = "rotate(" + newAngle + "deg)",
    keyframe_1 = "transform: rotate(" + currentAngle + "deg);",
    keyframe_2 = "transform: rotate(" + newAngle + "deg);",
    animationCSS;

  styleSheet.cssRules[animState][0].style.cssText = keyframe_1; // sets value at 0%
  styleSheet.cssRules[animState][1].style.cssText = keyframe_2; // sets value at 100%

  if (animState === 0) {
    animState = 1;
    animationCSS = "rotate_2 1s";
  } else {
    animState = 0;
    animationCSS = "rotate_1 1s";
  }

  document.getElementById("container").style.animation = animationCSS;
  document.getElementById("container").style.transform = transformCSS;

  currentAngle = newAngle;
};
```

```css
#container {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="rotateBtn">Rotate</button>
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you! I'll try to recreate this without jQuery.

Comment: It's actually very easy as I only used jQuery to select the elements. So most of the code will work with pure js

Comment: I must admit using keyframes is a pretty cool Idea. I'm seeing if this will actually work on my project

Comment: I removed the jQuery, so check out if that works for you